# Refresh Cognito access token after adding user to a Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Yello, I have the following scenario.

After first user login the users have to select their type, I got this working by calling a lambda that adds the user to appropriate Cognito Group.

After that call succeeds I want to refresh user session in my React App which I do by calling the following code:

```
refreshSession = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {     
    this.props.authenticatedUser.refreshSession(this.props.authenticatedUser.signInUserSession.refreshToken, () => {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(updatedAuthUser => {
          this.props.onUserAuthenticated(updatedAuthUser); // update redux state
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
        });
    });
  });
};
```

It does the job when it comes to updating the values of the idToken - the idToken payload has the updated user groups and roles.

The issue I am having is in an API call I do after the call to my refreshSession function defined above. The lambda call behaves as if the user does not belong to the Cognito Group that it was added to and I get a 403 response. If I logout and login again I can call the API successfully.

So effectively I am doing something like (pseudo code):

```
addUserToCognitoGroup()
  .then(() => {
    // user is added to Cognito Group
    refreshIdToken().then(() => {
      // my idToken seems to be refreshed
      doSomethingThatRequiresMembershipInTheGroup() // this API call returns 403 
  })
```

I assume it might have something to do with my code not refreshing access token, but I am struggling to find a way to correctly refresh the whole user session.

My package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^2.0.11",
  "aws-amplify": "^0.4.6",
  "aws-api-gateway-client": "^0.2.13",
  "aws-sdk": "^2.263.1",
  "aws-serverless-express": "^3.2.0",
  "aws4": "^1.6.0",
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "express": "^4.15.2",
  "graphql": "^0.13.2",
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "react": "^16.4.1",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
  "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "react-router": "^4.3.1",
  "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
  "react-table": "^6.8.6",
  "redux": "^4.0.0"
}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

After trying again today I noticed that I could avoid getting a 403 if I reloaded the page after the user was added to Cognito Group.

That got me to go and debug Amplify's Auth API and I noticed that it called a function named _setCredentialsFromSession at some point. So I went and modified my code to this (currentUserCredentials makes the call to _setCredentialsFromSession):

```
refreshSession() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.props.authenticatedUser.refreshSession(this.props.authenticatedUser.signInUserSession.refreshToken, () => {
    Auth.currentUserCredentials().then(() => {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(updatedAuthUser => {    
        this.props.onUserAuthenticated(updatedAuthUser);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          reject();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Feels a bit dirty, but it works now. If someone finds a better solution do let me know.